# Proving Inverses in Normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, inverse

I am trying to prove that $N_G(A)$ is a subgroup of $G$. I am given that $G$ is a group and $A\subseteq G$. Define $gAg^{-1}=\{gag^{-1}|a\in A\}$. Define the normalizer of $A$ in $G$ to the set:
$$
N_G(A)=\{g\in G|gAg^{-1}= A\}
$$
I have already proven that $N_G(A)$ is nonempty and that it is closed under the binary operation. The part I am struggling with is showing that $N_G(A)$ is closed under inverses. Here is what I have so far....

Let $x\in N_G(A)$. Then $xAx^{-1}=A$. Consider $x^{-1}A(x^{-1})^{-1}=x^{-1}Ax$. By substitution, $x^{-1}xAx^{-1}x=(1)A(1)=A$.

Is this a valid argument?

Lastly, I apologize if this a duplicate question. I tried looking and couldn't find something that helped me with my specific question.

Comment: $gAg^{-1}=a$ doesn't make sense, because $gAg^{-1}$ is a set but $a$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: @carmichael561 I am not multiplying the set. It is meaning for all $a\in A$ that operation holds. I will make the change in my question.

Comment: Firstly replace $gag^{-1}\subseteq A$ by $gag^{-1} \in A$. Secondly what you wrote is not the definition of the normalizer (since in general it won't necessarily contain inverses when $A$ is infinite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalizer of a subgroup $S \subset G$ is the set of all elements $g$ satisfying $gS=Sg$ as a set.

We only need to check for product, inverse and identity.

For the identity $i$, $iS=S=Si$ as a set, is clear.

Let $f, g \in N_G(S)$. Then $fS=Sf$ and $gS=Sg$. Then, $$
fgS = f(gS) = f(Sg) = (fS)g=(Sf)g = Sfg
$$

So $fg \in N_G(S)$.

Let $x \in N_G(S)$, then $xS=Sx$. Consider the set $x^{-1}S = \{ x^{-1}s : s\in S\}$. Note that $$Sx^{-1} = (x^{-1}x)Sx^{-1}=x^{-1}(xS)x^{-1} = x^{-1}(Sx)x^{-1}=(x^{-1}S)xx^{-1} = x^{-1}S$$

So $x \in N_G(S)$. Hence the normalizer is a subgroup of $G$.

The following is a very clever manipulation, one often used in group theory.

---

Clear out, the new definition is in town:

> $N_G(A) = \{ g \in G : gAg^{-1} = A\}$.

Identity : $iAi^{-1} = A$, obviously.

Product: Let $f,g \in N_G(A)$.then,
$$fg(A)(fg)^{-1} = (fg)A(g^{-1}f^{-1}) = f(gAg^{-1})f^{-1} = fAf^{-1} = A$$

Inverse: let $x \in N_G(A)$. Then $xAx^{-1} = A$.

Then, $$x^{-1} A (x^{-1})^{-1} = x^{-1}Ax = x^{-1}(x A x^{-1})x = (x^{-1}x) A (x^{-1}x) = A$$

Do you see why equality is important? If $xAx^{-1}$ were just contained in $A$, then the equality $ x^{-1}Ax = x^{-1}(x A x^{-1})x$ can't be written! Therein lies the crux of the proof. Of course, we are done.

Comment: I see your argument. Is there a way to do it in the notation I am using?

Comment: I shall try. If it comes I will edit my answer.

Comment: No, it won't come, because the definition you are using is skewed. I think the definition which I gave is correct.

Comment: Ok, I will have to look at the problem closer. Thank you for taking the time to help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @JessieByrnes You are welcome (to ask more questions, and get them answered).

Comment: Made significant changes to my question is regards to how I defined a normalizer. Is the way I applied the definition and substituted valid?

Comment: @JessieByrnes I will edit my answer, clearly showing you why the $=$ sign matters in the definition.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I did not see the last edit you made. You gave the correct argument for the inverse.

Comment: No worries! You just verified that I was on the right track. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JessieByrnes You are welcome (to ask more questions, and get them answered).

Comment: I believe that was all the questions I had for now. Thanks again.